# Load distribution panel, type of wood and thickness?

Tags: wood, load-bearing

I have a 1m2 (10ft2) object. This object weighs 400kg (880 pounds). I would like to spread the load over 2.5m2 (25ft2).

I'm wondering what type of wood/panel and how thick should that wood be. Are there any calculators?

I've been thinking about plywood or laminated wood, but don't know how thick these should be!

Comment: Is this going to be a shelf on the wall or a stand or what?

Comment: @Phaelaxz it is going to actually be a vocal booth! 1.2m x 1.2m but will be standing on a small 1m x 1m plate!